# The end single and double quotes do not display

Tags: csquotes

I am following Toni Farley's course "Latex for professional publication" and the single and double quotes are not displayed correctly. The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent  `single´  quotes, and ``double´´ quotes
\end{document}
```

produces the following output when typeset:

[image]

Comment: you need to use the ascii apostrophe `'` not the right quote `´`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add several examples.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\noindent  \textquotesingle single\textquotesingle\  quotes, and \textquotedbl double\textquotedbl \ or \textquotedblleft another double\textquotedblright\ quotes, or "another"
\end{document}
```